# Rails client side validation does not work on simple form association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, client-side-validation

I have a model User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :goal, :presence => true, :on => :update
  belongs_to :goal, :class_name => Goal, :foreign_key => "goal_id"
  ...
end
```

and on the form i have

```
<%= simple_form_for @users,:remote => true, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put, :multipart => true }, :validate => true do |f| %>
 <%= f.association :goal,:label => "My overall goal is clearing", :input_html => {:class => 'goals'},:include_blank => true %>
```

But the rails client side validation does not pick up the validation on the association, it lets me fill in blank for goal.

Does rails client side validation gem work for simple form association?

I am getting the below script on my html page

```
if (window.ClientSideValidations == undefined) window.ClientSideValidations = {};
if (window.ClientSideValidations.forms == undefined) window.ClientSideValidations.forms = {};
window.ClientSideValidations.forms['edit_user_14'] = {
    "type": "SimpleForm::FormBuilder",
    "error_class": "error",
    "error_tag": "span",
    "wrapper_error_class": "field_with_errors",
    "wrapper_tag": "div",
    "wrapper_class": "input",
    "wrapper": "default",
    "validators": {
        "user[mobile_number]": {
            "format": [{
                "message": "should be 10 digits",
                "with": /^\d{10}$/i
            }]
        },
        "user[profile_pic]": {
            "integrity": [{
                "message": "translation missing: en.activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.profile_pic.integrity"
            }],
            "processing": [{
                "message": "translation missing: en.activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.profile_pic.processing"
            }],
            "download": [{
                "message": "translation missing: en.activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.profile_pic.download"
            }],
            "format": [{
                "message": "Wrong file format",
                "with": /\.(gif|jpeg|jpg|png)$/i,
                "allow_blank": true
            }]
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you uncommented the code block in your config/initializers/client_side_validations.rb?
Is your rails.validations.js loading in your layout?

Comment: @Cadence96 yes i just updated the question with the script that gets loaded

Comment: Are you using jQuery gem? Have you tested it in a different and non associated model? Your code is different than the one I have from my rails.validations.js v3.1.4

Comment: @Cadence96 i use 3.2.0 .... its works on non associated models... only the association is not working

Comment: I tested it in an association, using :on => :update it failed.

Comment: I just opend an issue here https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues/453

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key distinction here is using `validates :goal_id ...` not `validates :goal ...`

Since this is an association, the real property on your ActiveRecord model (and in the underlying data store) is `goal_id`. That's what `client_side_validations` is looking for by default.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `ClientSideLavodation` gem can't find proper validation for association so just add

```
validates :goal_id, :presence => true, :on => :update
```

to your model.